# Proof for value of sum of sine and cosine

Tags: trigonometry

I have come across those sums of sine and cosine, while trying to show that windmills dont move without external force. Although it is clear that should be the case, i'm stuck in proofing it. I wonder if there is some way to proof
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right) = 0 \tag{1} \label{1} $$

In case of sine the proof is easy because of simple symmetry
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right) = 0 \tag{2}$$

Also if n is even $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right) = 0$ is easy to show.
So my question is: How do you prove or at least argue that $\eqref{1}$ holds for all n?

Comment: sine and cosine

Comment: More generic : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the sum as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})=Re\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i2\pi k/n}=
Re\left\{\frac{1-e^{i2\pi n/n}}{1-e^{i2\pi/n}}\right\}=0,\quad n>1$$

(Note that I used $k$ as the summation index, and $i$ as the imaginary unit.)

Comment: The questioner has the imaginary unit $i$ in the argument of the trig functions ....

Comment: @AndreaMori No, it's the sum index.

Comment: oh my! :) bad notation!

Comment: That's why I've changed it in my answer ... :)

Comment: yeah i thought i migth be confusing, but didnt thought we would need complex numbers

Comment: It's no real problem (no pun intended). As soon as we need $i$ as the imaginary unit (which is the case in my solution), we simply change the summation index.

Comment: could you elaborate $Re\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i2\pi k/n}=
Re\left\{\frac{1-e^{i2\pi n/n}}{1-e^{i2\pi/n}}\right\}$, i'm afraid it's a bit too fast for me.

Comment: I've used the formula for a geometric series: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}r^k=(1-r^n)/(1-r)$.

Comment: thank you, it's so simple :-).

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right).
$$
then for all $k=0,...,n-1$,
$$
\zeta^k=e^{2\pi ik/n}=\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}n\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}n\right).
$$
Since $\zeta^n=1$ but $\zeta\neq1$ we must have
$$
1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\cdots+\zeta^{n-1}=0.
$$
Take real and imaginary parts.

Comment: it should be $\zeta^k=e^{2k\pi i/n}$, right?