# $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)=0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, proof-writing

How would you prove $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)=0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$$

We tried induction first, but it doesnt seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/746457/42969.

Comment: The centroid of a regular polyhydron is at its circumcenter.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Try to use geometric sum to prove that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi k i}{n}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

A simple geometric interpretration comes if we divide by $n$ so we're sayng averages, not sums, are $0$. The cosines and sines are respectively the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a regular $n$-gon of circumradius 1, centred on the origin with a vertex at $(1,\,0)$. By symmetry the vertices' coordinates average to the origin.